# Ctrl-Space for autocompletion in text editor for scripts doesn't work anymore?

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

What is the new shortcut for *autocompletion* in the editor for scripts (macros)? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't work anymore in Blender 2.82+?

Comment: There is no *real macro scripting* in blender so you're most likely the only one person in the world of blender calling a script a *macro*... and the *Script Editor* a *Macro Editor*. Anyway, if you like it that way I don't mind. Cheers

Comment: Google: "Blender macro" = 9 Mill, "Blender script" = 13 Mill. Ok, times change :-). thx for the info.

But text editor is meant to edit scripts (unlike console). Right?

Comment: Made my day! ...Usually you need the python console to write/edit a script in the text editor :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't look enough in preferences.

The new shotcut is <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: How do you enter the key icons? I'ld like to learn.

Comment: Ah. thx. <kbd>Key</kbd>